# changing a global variable within a class function in python

Tags: python, class, global-variables

I've seen questions asked on this before, but I'm not able to recreate the alteration of global variables within a class function:

```
test = 0
class Testing:
    def add_one():
        global test
        test += 1
```

when I type in

```
Testing.add_one
print (test)
```

It prints "0".  How do I get the function in the class to add one to test?

Thank you!

Comment: that's what I am doing

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the function add_one

```
test = 0    
class Testing:
    def add_one():
        global test
        test += 1
Testing.add_one()
print (test)
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call the function. And if you did you will get a TypeError

It should be like this

```
test = 0
class Testing(object):
    @staticmethod
    def add_one():
        global test
        test += 1

Testing.add_one()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

[image]

```
test = 0
class Testing:
    def add_one(self):
        global test
        test += 1
        print(test)

t = Testing()
t.add_one()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call the method. Then only it will increment the value of the variable `test`.

```
In [7]: test = 0
   ...: class Testing:
   ...:     def add_one():
   ...:         global test
   ...:         test += 1                                                                                                                                                                

# check value before calling the method `add_one`
In [8]: test
Out[8]: 0

# this does nothing
In [9]: Testing.add_one
Out[9]: <function __main__.Testing.add_one()>

# `test` still holds the value 0
In [10]: test
Out[10]: 0

# correct way to increment the value
In [11]: Testing.add_one()

# now, check the value
In [12]: test
Out[12]: 1
```